# Can't get ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"] to work for me

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am doing something wrong, that much I know. :) I am trying to display a simple breadcrumb on a page. I have this in a view:

```
@if (ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString() == "Index")
{
    <li>
        // This displays "Matter"
        @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"]
    </li>
}
else
{  
    <li>
        // This displays a hyperlink "Matter", 
        // but the Href goes to "MyApp/Matter/Matter"
        <a href="@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString()">
            @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"]
        </a>
    </li>
}
```

In the above scenario, I have my Route.cs file set up to be "MyApp/Matter" which corresponds to an "Index" action on my "MatterController".

Clicking the link brings you to "MyApp/Matter/Matter" which does not work.

Any thoughts on how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting a relative path in the anchor tag.  It's evaluating to:

```
  <a href="Matter">Matter</a>
```

That (Matter) gets appended to your current URL which, in this case, I can only assume is "MyApp/Matter".  The result is "MyApp/Matter/Matter".

You need to specify an absolute URL or a more complete relative URL -- ../Matter would work in this case.

Beyond that, I can't help you without understanding a little more about what you're trying to do.

1. Where do you want the breadcrumb to take them?  What's in the breadcrumb in relation to what they're looking at?
2. Is MyApp in your example the directory that contains the app or is it an area within your application?
3. I can only gather that Matter is the controller, but what's the action?  If you're getting a link displayed then it's not currently looking at the Index action.

Comment: Sorry for the late resolution - was away for a bit. Thanks, ../Matter worked.